# Map database records to LDAP users

Tags: ldap

I want to provide external authentication to use either a database or an ldap server to store and authenticate users.

In my application I store data in a database and each entry/row is mapped to an user.

With an external user database I can simply use the user's primary key to map the application data to the user, but which ldap attribute is similar to the database's "unique primary key"?

Comment: You could use the `uuid` attribute, if your LDAP user entries have it. Mine do, and I've been doing that for eight years.

Comment: @EJP did you mean 'entryUUID'?

Comment: Depends on your LDAP server implementation. Most have some form of a UUID (GUID, ObjectGuid, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Distinguished Name (DN) is unique.

Comment: Yeah but isn't there something I can directly use for my database records 'uid INT NOT NULL'? The DN is a string but I would like to have an int or some number ...

Comment: @Pali maybe `entryUUID` as 128-bit integer

Comment: If there is nothing better I will go with uuid then